# FilePermission error thrown when using multiple threads to access sqlite database

Tags: java, database, multithreading, sqlite

I have two databases: postgres and sqlite. I'm creating threadpool to do some independent tasks which fetch data from different or same tables. It works fine for postgres but sqlite connections throw FilePermission exception to read the .db files.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html).

What it says, is that there are three possibilities for you:

1. Single-thread
2. Multi-thread
3. Serialized

In `Single-thread` you should have one and only one connection and use it across all threads.

In `Multi-thread` you must have a separated connection for each thread.

And in `Serialized` mode you can have it as you want, but it may be slower.

The link also provides the way to set the threading modes.